What is a valid browserVersion value for firefox in webdriver.io configuration capabilities to find a matching browser?
When starting webdriver.io tests against firefox browser, I get
Error: Couldn't find a matching firefox browser for tag "128.4.0esr" on platform "linux"
My wdio configuration has following capabilities configuration:
 [{
    'wdio:maxInstances': 1,
    browserName: 'firefox',
    **browserVersion: '128.4.0esr',**
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        args: ['--headless']
    }]

What is the correct browserVersion syntax for firefox?
Tried the following without success:

128
128.4.0
128.4.0esr
esr_128.4.0


It may or may not apply to Puppeteer, but Firefox's internal designation for its versions (e.g., in extension manifests) leaves off the micro version (128.4, 128.4a1, 128.4b1, etc.).
